# Specify tangle place in resulting file

Tags: org-mode

For example, I have a two blocks like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
;; first block
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
;; second block
#+END_SRC
```

I need the first block to be placed after the second block in resulting file after org-babel-tangle.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using a named block and noweb syntax:

```
#+NAME: first
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle no
;; first block
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
;; second block
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes :noweb yes
  <<first>>
#+END_SRC
```